# Background image is going out of row < 768 px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out why the picture is going out of the row on our contact page using Bootstrap 3. When I minimize the screen on google chrome it is looking fine, but when I look at the page on an iPhone - it is looking like this:

(*I can see the Stack picture upload function is not working. Therefore I am linking to the picture on the domain --imgbb instead*):

I have a thought of it could be the below class there is messing things up. I have to use a prefix for the some of the core classes I use, so I am not affecting the whole site. In this case, I wanted to make a 20px margin on the page when the screen is `< 768px`. Someone suggested me to wrap all the code in a row because the container is called in the backend and have its own style.

```
/* Make a 20px margin on mobile devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
        .mk .row {
            margin-left: 20px !important;
            margin-right: 20px !important;
        }
}
```

I would like that the background picture on the banner is taking full width on mobile. Does anybody have an idea on how I can solve this? I am pretty much stuck.

I tried to sort out the code there is not relevant for the question.

```css
.mk .row [class*="col-"] {
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    
    .mk-page-header { 
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7), rgba(0,0,0,.7)), url(https://vou.dk/Cms/333780ed-bd2b-4513-9186-af155e172a57.jpg)
        no-repeat; 
        position: relative; 
        background-size: cover; 
    }
    .mk .row {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .page-caption { 
        padding-top: 170px; 
        padding-bottom: 174px; 
    }
    .page-title { 
        font-size: 46px; 
        line-height: 1; 
        color: #fff; 
        font-weight: 600; 
        text-align: center; 
    }
    
    .card-section { 
        position: relative; 
        bottom: 140px;
        margin-bottom: -80px;
    }
    .card-block { 
        padding: 20px 80px 50px 80px;
        box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px grey;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .section-title { 
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .img-responsive-mk {
        width: 35% !important;
    }
   
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .img-responsive-mk {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        .card-block {
            padding: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .page-title {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        .mk-heading {
          font-size: 24px;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        h3 {
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        /* Make a 20px margin on mobile devices */
        .mk .row {
            margin-left: 20px !important;
            margin-right: 20px !important;
        }
        /* Owerwrite the core padding on a row */
        .contact-icon .row {
          margin-left: 0px !important;
            margin-right: 0px !important;
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="mk row" style="background-color: white;">
 <!-- page-header -->
  <div class="mk-page-header">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="page-caption">
                      <h1 class="page-title">KONTAKT VORES SUPPORT</h1>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Card Section -->
  <div class="card-section">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="card-block">
              <div class="contact-icon row">
                  <div class="section-title">
                      <h2>HAR DU SPØRGSMÅL?</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <div class="contact-icon row">
                          <div class="col-xs-4">
                              <a href="tel:+4512345678">
                                <img class="img-responsive-mk center-block" src="https://vou.dk/Static/Cms/6dfe32ba-7cff-443d-ab73-016dd2f6dca7.jpg"></img>
                              </a>
                              <a href="tel:+4512345678"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Ring til os</h3></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-4">
                              <a href="mailto:info@company.dk">
                                <img class="img-responsive-mk center-block"  src="https://vou.dk/Static/Cms/57e5b8a2-871d-487f-90e4-ae8b8d170ca2.jpg"></img>
                              </a>
                              <a href="mailto:info@company.dk"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Skriv til os</h3></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-4">
                              <a href="https://www.facebook.com//">
                                <img class="img-responsive-mk center-block"  src="https://vou.dk/Static/Cms/3caa853e-7da3-4e1f-9aa2-a04ee71901c9.jpg"></img>
                              </a>
                              <a href="https://www.facebook.com//"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Facebook</h3></a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by your .container-fluid and #chrome element. Container-fluid applies padding but you cancel it out with padding: 0; on #chrome. You have to solve that part differently.

Solution 1: I suggest moving container-fluid class to #front element. 
But that is up to you. But .container-fluid is needed to prevent the image spilling out because rows have negative margins (that's why they are spilling over) and it's usually good to wrap them inside a container to prevent this.

Solution 2: Remove row from `<div class="mk row" style="background-color: white; --darkreader-inline-bgcolor:#212127;" data-darkreader-inline-bgcolor="">`
And then wrap all other rows in a .container except the .mk-page-header.

Advice: When testing and searching for this kind of issues use dev-tools in your browser. It will make your life so much easier. Dev-tools are great and a very powerful tool. Once you get a hang of it you will see it's hard to do without :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I use a `container-fluid` can I overwrite that with fx mk container-fluid, so I do not affect otherpages. The problem is that I am quite sure that the container-fluid is called at the backend, so If I make one in our cms system, there is 2.

Comment: How can you see this graphic mistake in dev tools? For me it is looking how it should in dev tools. It is first when I see on my iPhone I can see the problem.

Comment: To find the element that spills over try resizing the browser to the size you want (mobile) or select a device in device toolbar. Then use element inspector and hover over the part that spills over the page.
I updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. It is starting to look like something now. If you have time it could be cool if you could take a look at the link in my question. I can see the padding is a little bit big `< 768px`. I tried to remove the padding left and right, but does not look like it is doing something?

Comment: Sure. I took a look. So your mk class is overriding a lot of styles on rows and cols. So I would remove it from the div element mentioned in the main answer above.  Try it out and you will see. 
Also once you have container applied you don't need to nest them except if you specifically want this. So you can remove it from the child element inside .card-section cause it's already applied to one of the parent elements.

Comment: Thanks again. Everything with mk should be gone now. I think the page is caching the css, so please see the page in Inkognito. I can see that if I remove the padding-left and right form the container, it would like more nice on mobile? I think the container is making the big padding?

Comment: If I could get the `padding-left:15px` and `padding-right:15px` away from the container there is nesting the `class="card-section"`. Then everything would work it seems like. But that container is a bootstrap class, so I have to overwrite it somehow?

Comment: Good to hear.
If you can't remove the container there then.... for example bootstrap 4 has a lot of utility/helper classes for different stuff. One of them are spacing classes. For example .p-0 applies padding: 0, .px-0 applies padding right and left 0... You can do something similar and add that class to the container which would remove the additional padding.
The other way is to just reference it directly in the CSS with .card-section > .container and add padding:0;

Comment: Thanks again. Shoot it is the last i am missing here. I added: `@media (max-width: 768px) {.card-section > .container {
          padding: 0px;
        }}`, but it is not doing anything?

Comment: I checked the site and do not see it in CSS. 
I also see that another thing is causing overflow of an element. Remove
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
Fixed px widths are usually not good when dealing with responsive sites. Try using %

Comment: Ah yes I see it now when I open in Inkognito window. So I can see the `h1` and `p` in the pageheader now makes no padding on the text. Should I give them a seperate class?=

Comment: That's up to you. You can disable the cache in dev-tools settings so it will reload all you resources each time you refresh and have dev-tools open.

Comment: Are you still there? Something is very wrong, and it is live now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the row margin with padding and make sure box-sizing is set to padding box like this:

replace this:

```
/* Make a 20px margin on mobile devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .mk .row {
        margin-left: 20px !important;
        margin-right: 20px !important;
    }
}
```

with this:

```
/* Make a 20px margin on mobile devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .mk .row {
        padding-left: 20px !important;
        padding-right: 20px !important;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}
```

by setting box-sizing to border-box, you're telling it not to increase its' size by adding padding.
Also, using !important is bad practice and not recommended unless you're overriding inline styles or overriding nasty selectors.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried your code in the link I gave in my question, but it is not doing anything :-(

Comment: you have another section with     `.mk .row { margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }` which causes the same issue. Try to comment that out.

Comment: Thank you again. I just outcomment the code, but still no result on the link in my question. But thank you a lot for giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS rule:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .mk .row {
        margin-left: 20px !important;
        margin-right: 20px !important;
    }
}
```

applies to an element with the `row` class that's a descendant of an element with the `mk` class. Therefore, it doesn't apply to this `div`:

```
<div class="mk row" style="background-color: white;">
```

which seems to be your main wrapper. Either remove the `row` class from there (which is IMO the preferred solution), or replace the rule with this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .mk.row {
        margin-left: 20px !important;
        margin-right: 20px !important;
    }
}
```

Notice there are no space between `.mk` and `.row`, which means the rule will be applied to an element with **both** the `mk` and `row` classes.